# Load text from web during xml parsing in Windows 8 Async

Tags: c#, xml, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I have a unique issue, I want to get the name of an application from it's AppID while I convert an XML file into objects. This is the code I'm using at present:

```
        if (xdoc.Element("Application") != null)
        {
            var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("AppID")
                       select new APP
                       {
                           AppID = query.Value,
                           AppName = GetName(query.Value).ToString(),
                       };
            itemGridView.DataContext = data;
        }
```

This is the code I'm using to convert the GUID into an app name using Microsoft's Store API. I can confirm that it does return the app name. I'm just unsure how I can get this to display.

```
  private async Task<string> GetName(string guid)
        {
            try
            {
                string link = "https://services.apps.microsoft.com/browse/6.2.9200-1/615/en-NZ_en-NZ/c/NZ/cp/10005001/Apps/{0}";
            string url = string.Format(link, guid);

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
            var xmlString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            XmlDocument NameXML = new XmlDocument();
            NameXML = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(new Uri(url));
            string sAppName = NameXML.GetElementsByTagName("T")[0].ChildNodes[0].NodeValue.ToString();
            return sAppName;

        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return guid;
        }
    }
```

I think my problem is with the async / await tasks. I've just been exposed to it now... how would I load up the App Name alongside the AppID when I parse the xml file?

The output that's being displayed when I run the app is "System.Threading.Tasks.Task[System.String]" (The objects load and the links and everything works fine, its just that the above is displayed instead of the app name).

I've been debugging using breakpoints, it appears that the GetName method only seems to be triggered later on, I'm not sure however.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line :

```
AppName = GetName(query.Value).ToString(),
```

To this :

```
AppName = await GetName(query.Value),
```

`GetName` will return `Task<string>` instead of string when not *awaited*. And the method where above code resides required to be `async` because of using `await` inside that method :

```
private async void SomeMethod()
{
    ....
    if (xdoc.Element("Application") != null)
    {
        var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("AppID")
                   select new APP
                   {
                       AppID = query.Value,
                       AppName = await GetName(query.Value),
                   };
        itemGridView.DataContext = data;
    }
    ....
}
```

**UPDATE :**

As you already noticed, LINQ has very limited support for `async/await` currently. So to workaround this limitation, we can use normal for loop to avoid calling async function inside LINQ :

```
private async void SomeMethod()
{
    ....
    if (xdoc.Element("Application") != null)
    {
        var query = from query in xdoc.Descendants("AppID")
                   select query.Value;
        var data = new List<App>();
        foreach (var q in query)
        {
            data.Add(new App{ AppId = q, AppName = await GetName(q) });
        }
        itemGridView.DataContext = data;
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: But the AppName is a string inside the xml query isn't it? I'm getting 'Cannot await string' error.

Comment: try to remove `.ToString()` after calling `GetName` method. I updated my answer

Comment: but it's still thinking its a string since AppID and AppName are values inside the APP class

The 'await' operator may only be used in a query expression within the first collection expression of the initial 'from' clause or within the collection expression of a 'join' clause

Comment: good point. I've never used await inside LINQ before, so I didn't aware of that limitation until now.